# Delete extra characters apart from starting and ending in a string in python

Tags: python

I have data of the form:

```
"C def geh.#- ijk "<> ""^^xsd:date.
```

Now for the last part of the above string i.e. "C def geh.#- ijk "<> ""^^xsd:date  -- i.e the part which begins and ends with quotes. I want to keep just the beginning and ending quotes and delete all the other quotes and <>, etc. except #,-,.,_,(,) which come in between. Can someone please suggest how can i do it. My expected output should appear as:

```
"C def geh.#- ijk "^^xsd:date.
```

Comment: `<A> <B> "C def geh.#- ijk "<> ""^^xsd:date.` is a string ? I.e. `'<A> <B> "C def geh.#- ijk "<> ""^^xsd:date.'`?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks for your comment. I was referring to "C def geh.#- ijk "<> "" as string. I left out the rest as I want to delete extra characters starting from the first appearance of " to the last appearance of "

Comment: @TimCastelijns I have simplified the question, you may take "C def geh.#- ijk "<> ""^^xsd:date as string now

Comment: As in `'"C def geh.#- ijk "<> ""^^xsd:date'`?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes you are correct

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there always will be a match:

```
import re

def cleanup(str): 
    return ''.join(re.match('(\"[^\"]+\").*?(\^\^xsd\:date\.)', str).groups())

>>> s = """"C def geh.#- ijk "<> ""^^xsd:date."""
>>> cleanup(s)
'"C def geh.#- ijk "^^xsd:date.'
```

UPDATE If the dot at the end of the string might or might not appear, use this (and I forgot the dollar sign to mark the end):

```
def cleanup(str): 
    return ''.join(re.match('(\"[^\"]+\").*?(\^\^xsd\:date\.?)$', str).groups())

>>> s = '"1980-"05"-26"^^xsd:date'
>>> cleanup(s)
'"1980-"^^xsd:date'
```

If you want to handle the situation when there is no match (e.g. return empty string), then it could be done like this:

```
def cleanup(str):
    try:
        return ''.join(re.match('(\"[^\"]+\").*?(\^\^xsd\:date\.?)$', str).groups())
    except AttributeError:
        return ''

>>> cleanup("asdfadf")
''
```

UPDATE after getting more explanations from OP (need to cleanup the contents between the first and last quotes and return the rest unchanged):

```
def cleanup(str):
    left_index = s.find('\"')
    right_index = s.rfind('\"')
    if left_index==right_index: 
        return str
    else:
        cleaned = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z\#\-\.\_\(\)]','',s[left_index+1:right_index])
        return str[:left_index+1]+cleaned+str[right_index:]

>>> cleanup(s)
'"1980-05-26"^^xsd:date'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not working when s='"1980-"05"-26"^^xsd:date'.  It gives me the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: In this case, which of the quotes should be preserved? Also, this match does not work because there is no dot in the end.

Comment: Actually for cleanup(s) I want the answer to be '"1980-05-26"^^xsd:date. I just want the unwanted characters i.e. quotes to be deleted and not any other character

Comment: Yes. And I may not necessarily have xsd:date in my expression